# Streaming video in iOS and android device: DASH or HLS?

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I want to implement video streaming in both android(4.x+) and iOS(3.x+) devices.

I have a look at DASH(Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP) and HLS (HTTP Live streaming), but it made me confused. Many people say DASH will be the trend in future. Is that right?

What should I use to implement video streaming now?
Any information: dis/advantage of those, supported browser and devices would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason to use HLS is Apple's arbitrary App Store rule that HLS must be used for video streaming over cellular network.

As for technical issues, HLS is somewhat more widely supported on iOS and Android, but MPEG DASH is supported in web browsers without the need for plugins.

Comment: Thanks. And what about performance and maximum concurrent client?

Comment: The overhead for content distribution is basically identical.

Comment: Do you know which android devices can use DASH, I only found that implement DASH using dash.js(https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki) work with any browser have Media source extension(chrome/IE11). Is it still right in android device? Or it only works on PC?

Comment: I don't think neither the android stock browser nor Android Chrome supports it yet. There are a few commercial players available for license.

Comment: Thanks @vipw. Hope it will support DASH soon.